# Beginner JS code works in Brackets but not in a normal Browser

Tags: javascript, brackets

I'm currently learning JS and I ran into an odd issue. I'm using Brackets and while my code works in the Brackets Live Preview feature, it seems to fail when I open it in my regular browser.

```js
function ipchk() {
var ip = document.getElementById("iptext").value;
if (document.getElementById("iptext").value!="") {
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};
getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/' + ip).then(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("ipwrite").innerHTML = "The IP currently checked is " + ip + "." + "<br> <br>";
  document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = "The country is " + data.country + ".";
    document.getElementById("countryCode").innerHTML = "The country code is " + data.countryCode + ".";
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "The city is " + data.city + ".";
    document.getElementById("isp").innerHTML = "The ISP is " + data.isp + ".";
    document.getElementById("timezone").innerHTML = "The timezone is " + data.timezone + ".";
}, );
}
else {
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("countryCode").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("isp").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("timezone").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("ipwrite").innerHTML = "Please input a valid IP address before searching.";
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>IP Locator</title>
<body>

<input type="text" id="iptext">
<button type="button" onclick="ipchk()";>GO.</button>

<p id="ipwrite"></p>
<p id="country"></p>
<p id="countryCode"></p>
<p id="city"></p>
<p id="isp"></p>
<p id="timezone"></p>
</body>
<script src="locator.js"></script>
</html>
```

Any insight on how I can correct this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How does it **fail**? Do you get any errors? Is it not showing what it should? BTW, your provided code is missing a curly brace `}`. You also shouldn't be creating functions within an `if` statement. Your `getJSON` function should be outside of everything.

Comment: If I use Brackets live preview, it loads correctly and displays the info.

Comment: However, if I use a normal browser, the info simply doesn't load.

Comment: No errors sadly. Thank you for the feedback, I will check.

Comment: I just checked, the code actually works. How are you opening it in a normal browser? (I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean by that)..

Comment: Is the `locator.js` file in the same folder as the `html` file that you're opening locally in a browser?

Comment: Yes, it is. I fixed it though. I'm an idiot, UBlock was blocking the website I was using to get the geo info. :( Thanks so much for the help guys.

Comment: @Robert that would've been my next guess - check whether adblock, etc. is blocking the ip service ..

Comment: @Robert You should delete this question as it was not an issue with your code.

Comment: @Robert better yet, you should answer your own qustion, to help future 'idiots' when they fall in the same hole.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

UBlock Origin was blocking the website. Since the Chrome windows that Brackets opens does not have any extensions, it worked well.